# Make a graph from the outcome of Floyd Warshall Algorithm

Tags: java, swing

I still don't know how to make use of the Swing. Basically, I just want to output an illustration of the graph after I enter the vertices and the weight of each edges. The degree of each vertices is just straight. For example, if <1,2> have an edge of 8 and <2,1> have an edge of 3, what will happen is that it will just form a straight line in the illustration which will make it more confusing and distracting. I can't seem to imitate the looks of the graph here.

[image: This is an example of the looks of the graph that I want to achieve]

This is my code below.

```
import javax.swing.*;    
import java.awt.*;    
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;    
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.QuadCurve2D;
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class ShowGraph extends JFrame {
    private final int[][] graph;
    private final int[] xCoordinates;
    private final int[] yCoordinates;

    public ShowGraph(int[][] graph, int[] xCoordinates, int[] yCoordinates) {
        this.graph = graph;
        this.xCoordinates = xCoordinates;
        this.yCoordinates = yCoordinates;

        setTitle("Graph Illustration");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500, 500);

        GraphPanel graphPanel = new GraphPanel();
        add(graphPanel);

        JButton closeButton = new JButton("Close");
        closeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dispose();
            }
        });
        add(closeButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    class GraphPanel extends JPanel {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            int radius = 20;

            for (int i = 0; i < graph.length; i++) {
                int x = xCoordinates[i];
                int y = yCoordinates[i];

                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.fillOval(x - radius, y - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
                g.drawString(String.valueOf(i + 1), x, y);

                for (int j = 0; j < graph.length; j++) {
                    if (graph[i][j] != 0 && graph[i][j] != Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                        int x2 = xCoordinates[j];
                        int y2 = yCoordinates[j];

                        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                        g.drawLine(x, y, x2, y2);
                        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                        int labelX = (x + x2) / 2;
                        int labelY = (y + y2) / 2;
                        g.drawString(String.valueOf(graph[i][j]), labelX, labelY);
                    }
                }
            }

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));

            for (int i = 0; i < graph.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < graph.length; j++) {
                    if (graph[i][j] != 0 && graph[i][j] != Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                        int x1 = xCoordinates[i];
                        int y1 = yCoordinates[i];
                        int x2 = xCoordinates[j];
                        int y2 = yCoordinates[j];

                        drawArrow(g2d, x1, y1, x2, y2);

                        QuadCurve2D curve = new QuadCurve2D.Float(x1, y1, (x1 + x2) / 2, (y1 + y2) / 2, x2, y2);
                        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                        g2d.draw(curve);

                        drawArrow(g2d, x2, y2, (int) curve.getCtrlX(), (int) curve.getCtrlY());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void drawArrow(Graphics2D g, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            double angle = Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1);
            int arrowSize = 10;
            int dx = (int) (arrowSize * Math.cos(angle));
            int dy = (int) (arrowSize * Math.sin(angle));
            g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
            g.drawLine(x2, y2, x2 - dx - dy, y2 - dy + dx);
            g.drawLine(x2, y2, x2 - dx + dy, y2 - dy - dx);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe use an external program/library to do the job - for example https://graphviz.org/ or https://plantuml.com/

Comment: The code you posted is missing the initiation of the graph and coordinates arrays.  Your drawing code has to determine whether a graph edge can be drawn with a straight line or an arc.